# Is it possible to get the innerHTML of a directive containing an ng-repeat before angular removes it from the DOM during bootstrapping?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a style guide and want to add syntax highlighting and code samples dynamically without having to copy/paste and escape the code for each item. The idea is that for each `bb-prism` directive, I include a `bb-sample` element that contains my code sample. The `bb-prism` directive clones the innerHTML of the code sample, creates `pre` and `code` elements, and then copies the clone into the `code` element. It's pretty slick except for when using `ng-repeat`. Angular seems to remove the `ng-repeat` before my `prism` directive can copy it.

```
<bb-prism>
    <h2>Multiple Addresses</h2>
    <bb-sample>
        <!-- Doesn't work with ng-repeat -->
        <bb-address address="address" ng-repeat="address in addresses"> </bb-address>
    </bb-sample>
</bb-prism>
```

The expected result is that the sample code should render:

```
<bb-address address="address" ng-repeat="address in addresses"> </bb-address>
```

Instead of:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: address in addresses -->
```

Here's a working example:

http://codepen.io/rustydev/pen/77fc7dc3e5365f10ebfabd54440f07c7/

Comment: How about simply copying the code out before you turn on angular using manual bootstrapping? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with numerous approaches, including using `pre-compile` in a stripped down version and couldn't log the html to console.

I propose an alternate approach that will show only the original clean markup and without any angular internal classes added

It uses script tag templates, `$templateCache` and `ng-include`.

Here's a rough ( but working) proof of concept setting markup in a textarea for now

View

```
<div test template ="repeat">
  <h3>repeating items example</h3>

  <!-- Our snippet template -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="repeat">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
  </script>
  <!-- include same template -->
  <ng-include src="'repeat'"></ng-include>

  <!-- source display -->
  <h3>source</h3>
  <textarea style="width:100%"></textarea>

</div>
```

Directive

```
.directive('test', function($templateCache) {

  return {
    scope: {template: '@'},
    link: function(scope, elem) {
       var code =$templateCache.get(scope.template);
       elem.find('textarea').val(code.trim())
    }
  }    
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rqZSTaCRCVQXUPgYwHEC?p=preview)**</kbd>

Note that there are gulp and grunt scripts that can compile whole directory of html files into `$templateCache` also and put them in a `run()` block

Another thought is use `ng-include` or `templateUrl(function)` for each of your html prism components and use $templateCache to get whole block of html and use `find()` on that to get the uncompiled innerHTML of `<bb-sample>`

EDIT: [More comprehensive demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ohrr43gX1AD2b7kYwfo2?p=preview)