# Have trouble when try to multi-transclude ng-repeated contents in Angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Inspired by [Kara Erickson](https://twitter.com/karaforthewin)'s amazing speak [Reusable Components in Angular: Design patterns, transclusion, and more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF_ObGgzGE8), and the [post](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/creating-components-p3-angular2-directives). I try to transclude the iterative contents, and expect each of them be transcluded to one specific slot.

Just see the demo to know what I mean.

```js
angular.module("slots", [])
angular.module("slots")
    .factory("MultiTransclude", function () {
        return {
            // multi-transclude function by "Kara Erickson"
            // https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/creating-components-p3-angular2-directives
            transclude: function transclude(elem, transcludeFn) {
                transcludeFn(function (clone) {
                    angular.forEach(clone, function (cloneEl) {
                        if (cloneEl.nodeName !== "#text") {
                            var targetName = cloneEl.attributes["transclude-to"].value;
                            var target = elem.find("[transclude-id='" + targetName + "']");
                            if (target.length) {
                                target.append(cloneEl);
                            } else {
                                cloneEl.remove();
                                throw new Error("Target not found. Please specify the correct transclude-to attribute.");
                            }
                        }

                    })
                })
            }
        }
    })
    .controller("slotCtrl", function() {
        //make the slot-content configurable
        this.items = [
          {
            name: "header",
            content: "I am header"
          },
          {
            name: "body",
            content: "I am body"
          },
          {
            name: "footer",
            content: "I am footer"
          }
        ]
    })
    .directive("slotWrapper", function(MultiTransclude) {
        return {
            template: `<div style="width: 50%; margin: 30px auto">
                         <div style="background: red" transclude-id="header"></div>
                         <div transclude-id="body" style="height: 100px;background: #eee" ></div>
                         <div style="background: green" transclude-id="footer"></div>
                       </div>`,
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
                MultiTransclude.transclude(elem, transclude);
            }
        }
  
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="slots">
  <div ng-controller="slotCtrl as slot">
    <p style="margin: 10px auto; padding-left: 20px">I expect the "slot-wrapper" as plain template directive, which has pre-defined the style and layout of slots in which transclude the "content" I truely concern.</p>
      <p style="margin: 10px auto; padding-left: 20px">In the first example , as you can see, it's ok to transclude the simple plain content to the specific "slot"</p>
    
    
    <slot-wrapper>
      <div transclude-to="header">I am header</div>
      <div transclude-to="body">I am body</div>
      <div transclude-to="footer">I am footer</div>
    </slot-wrapper>
    
<p style="margin: 10px auto; padding-left: 20px">In the second example , I want to make the slot-content configurable, and try to iterate the re-configed text-content array and expect the each of the text-content be transclude to the right slot. However, some weird error I cannot understand, and actually, I can never get the actual transcluded content from the transcludeFn as I expect. </p>
    <slot-wrapper>
      <div ng-repeat="item in slot.items" transclude-to="{{item.name}}">{{item.content}}</div>
    </slot-wrapper>


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't loop over an ng-repeat clone like that. Look at all the nodes in the loop. There are text and comments but no elements yet

Comment: the error is because comments are also part of dom. Test for `nodeType ===1` and error goes away

Comment: @charlietfl 'There are text and comments but no elements yet ', yes, in the transcludeFn function, I expect the transcluded ng-repeated element is compiled ready, however it's not ready except the comment. But why?

Comment: @charlietfl I try to put the transcludeFn in the $timeout or setTimeout to expect the transcluded element is ready, but failed. 'You can't loop over an ng-repeat clone like that'. could you give some detail why can't do that ?

Comment: that part I'm not really sure why. I went through something similar a few days go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406261/is-it-possible-to-get-the-innerhtml-of-a-directive-containing-an-ng-repeat-befor/38407137#38407137

Comment: I think I know why, `transclude:true` usually uses `ng-transclude` in template. Angular has nowhere to compile that `ng-repeat` to place it. Also might have something to do with your isolated scope. Could try using your own `$compile` to get the elements from that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117862/discussion-between-yqfang-and-charlietfl).